# Referencing External Resources from Jar

Tags: java, sqlite, jar, dependencies

I have a question regarding a Java project being developed in Netbeans. My application references a SQLITE database and various text files that will have information in it, but will also be modified through the Java application. The application will be built as a jar, but I realize that putting the database and text files inside the jar will make it read only. How do I structure my program so that building it includes the database and other modifiable files outside of the jar, but still allows me to reference them?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a command line argument? Or a config file (if you have a bunch of stuff you want to setup)? (I'm setting env variables, you could just as easily send them as arguments to the main())

```
java -Ddb.directory=/usr/local/dude/db -jar program.jar
```

or

```
java -Dconfig=/usr/local/dude/config.conf -jar program.jar
```

Comment: Hm, not sure I'm following your answer. Perhaps let me try to reframe the question: Where do I stick the db in the project so that when you build in netbeans it creates a folder with the jar and the db outside? Currently, I put the db in a separate folder called "resources" outside of the src folder. When I build, the db is not put in the same folder as the jar. Also, once I get that working, how do I reference the db?

Comment: Ok. I'm not a netbeans user, so I can't answer anything netbeans specific, sorry. I was answering as if you were going to distribute your jar'd application. In which case you don't need the database files, you just create all your tables from your Java program if they don't exist. If you don't want to do that you'll have to ship some empty SQLITE DB along with your jar.